# PuTTY "unknown option -o" when trying to connect

Tags: putty, google-cloud-datalab

Following the [getting started guide](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts) I attempt to create & connect to a datalab vm instance with the command:

```
datalab create demo
```

but I get the following pop-up:

[image: err message]

> unknown option "-o"

then, on ok-ing the error,

> connection broken
> Attempting to reconnect...

in the command prompt

Any idea how to have the keys generated a different way to allow me to connect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, you can try either running the `datalab connect demo` command from inside of Cloud Shell, or downgrading to version 153.0.0 of the Cloud SDK.

As for your error, this seems to be a newly introduced bug in the 154.0.0 release of the Cloud SDK.

Prior to that, running a command like `gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag=-o --ssh-flag=LogLevel=info demo` would have resulted in the "-o LogLevel=info" flag being stripped out of the command prior to it running on Windows.

With the most recent release (154.0.0), however, those flags are now passed to the SSH command as-is. This causes an error on Windows, as the PuTTY CLI does not support the -o flag.

I've filed https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1356 to track fixing this issue.

Sorry that you got hit by this.

Comment: The 155.0.0 build of the Cloud SDK went out today, and I've confirmed that it fixes the bug on Windows, so if you still see this, then please upgrade to 155.0.0