# PuTTY command line error while connecting to google datalab instance

Tags: putty, google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to connect to previously created instance in Google Cloude Compute Engine using datalab, or create a new one using Google Cloud SDK Shell:

```
    datalab connect nst
```

The program cannot connect, the error is the following:

```
    ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [C:\Users\Anastasia...\putty.exe] exited with returned code [1]
```

and there is a pop-up window from putty.exe with command line error:

```
    unknown option -"o"
```

Neither restart nor SDK shell reinstall doesn't help. What should I do? Thank you in advance.

I can connect to the instance through ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [PuTTy "unknown option -o" when trying to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782470/putty-unknown-option-o-when-trying-to-connect) and https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1356

Comment: sorry, didn't find it myself. Thank you!